# SendGrid's 550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed in Rail App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'v been trying to integrate SendGrid's SMTP settings directly for Rails App in order to avoid using add-ons from Heroku account. According to [SendGrid's document](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html), I follow instruction but strangely got error messages, please see below.

Heroku logs (error):

```
Net::SMTPFatalError (550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed
```

config/environment.rb

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain => 'heroku.com',
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: Did you set the `SENDGRID_USERNAME` and `SENDGRID_PASSWORD` in your heroku configs?

Comment: Thank you @yez, finally I got the emails! :)   How come SendGrid's dashboard not being updating quickly for email delivery?

Comment: Great, glad you got the solution. I'll add the answer so other people can benefit as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must ensure that the `SENDGRID_USERNAME` and `SENDGRID_PASSWORD` are set in your heroku config.

To do this from the command line:

`heroku config:set SENDGRID_USERNAME=my_username SENDGRID_PASSWORD=my_pass -app my_app`

Comment: Awesome, I will take this note. Thanks again.